# how to format the result of chyper query using neo4j-php-client in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, neo4j

I am using neo4j-php-client for query on neo4j database in laravel.

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
            ->addConnection('default', '****')
            ->build();
        $query = 'match (u:User{code:630480})-[:follows]->(b)-[:supplies]->(p) return p';
        $result = $client->run($query);
        foreach ($result->records() as $record) {
                $res[] = $record;
        }
        return $res;
```

The $res returns empty {}. While using the Neo4j Desktop returns the correct output for the query.

```
 [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

I also used json_encode for $res but again return {}. How to solve this?

Comment: Have a quick look at the [documentation](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client) - I think you need to use `$res[] = $record->values();`

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks, but values() returns only that specified value. I want whole record info and $res[] = $record->get('p') also returns {}.